# X11 Athena Widget Library on MAC OSX El-Capitan

Tags: macos, x11, packaging

I am getting the error message
ld: library not found for -lXaw

I know that i need to get X11 Athena Widget and i can do that through libxaw7 in a Linux Machine.

i am an OSX newbie and i am not sure if i can do that using homebrew? or another packaging manager?

is there any way to get that on OSX?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this fix for my error:

To check if you previously installed the library in your machine run the command on your terminal

I was looking for libxaw so i searched for "Xaw"

```
$ find /opt/X11/ -name "*Xaw*"
```

you should see an output of the search mine showed that i had libxaw7 which is what i was searching for

```
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw/XawImP.h    
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw/XawInit.h    
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw3d    
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw3d/Xaw3dP.h    
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw3d/XawImP.h    
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw3d/XawInit.h    
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw.6.dylib    
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw.7.dylib    
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw.8.dylib   
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw.dylib   
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw3d.8.dylib   
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw3d.dylib    
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw6.6.dylib    
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw6.dylib    
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw7.7.dylib    
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw7.dylib   
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw8.8.dylib    
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw8.dylib    
/opt/X11//share/doc/libXaw3d    
/opt/X11//share/man/man3/Xaw.3
```

If not you can use homebrew to download the libraries
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-x11

or you can just install xQuartz from
https://www.xquartz.org/

I was still getting the error then i realized that i needed to pass the flags

```
export CFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include && export LDFLAGS=-L/opt/X11/lib
```

learned that the toolchain won't find x11 in `/opt` from this post.

[Mountain Lion X11 libraries can't ./configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027868/mountain-lion-x11-libraries-cant-configure)